# Send an email on Submit to the email of logged in user through ASP.Net Website Administration

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, web, administration

I'm using the ASP.net Website Administration tool and I have set up all my users with a username, email and password. I was just curious if there is a way to send an email to the currently logged in user's correlated email after clicking the submit button?

Comment: Please don't append "C#" and such to the end of your titles. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Are you asking how to modify the website administration tool?

Comment: My apologies John, I just figured that'd make it easier for those who come across my title.

Comment: And Chris, no. I'm just asking if there is a code I could add to my Submit_Click that sends the form to the email of the user that is currently logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, though note that you cannot modify the administration tool, this is just a generic approach:

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("from address", Membership.GetUser().EmailAddress);
mm.Subject = "Test";
mm.Body = "Test";
smtp.Send(mm);
```

Comment: It says it does not contain a definition for 'EmailAddress' and no extension method 'EmailAddress' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Secrity.MembershipUser' could be found. Sorry for being so unknowledgeable, haha, but am I missing a reference as it states?

Comment: Is it just 'Email' instead of 'EmailAddress'?